# Number of solutions of the equation $z^p=(\overline{z})^q$

Tags: complex-numbers

So we have a complex number $z$ and we have to find number of solutions possible for the equation: $$z^p=(\overline{z})^q$$

So I created two cases:

Case-1: $p=q$. Clearly we can see the whole equation simplify into $z-\overline{z}=0$ or $\text{Im}(z)=0$. So entire real number axis is the solution, so number of solutions is infinite here.

Case-2: $p\ne q$, and let $p>q$. Here I run into problem. I tried to simplify the equation as:
$$|z|^p=|z|^q$$
$$|z|^p(|1-|z|^{q-p})=0$$
$$|z|^p=0,\,\,|z|=1$$

I can count 1 solution for $z=0$ but for other equation I am unsure how can I count the solution, so I require the help here. Every help is appreciated.

Comment: If $|z|=1$, then $\overline z=z^{-1}$. Hence, our equation becomes $z^{p+q}-1=0$. This means, if $p\neq q$ there are $p+q+1$ solutions of $z^p=(\overline z) ^q$.

Comment: @Jochen oh I see, I didn't thought that way. Thank you very much!

Comment: Are $p$ and $q$ necessarily positive integers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $p\not=q$ we can pair the equation with its conjugate:

$z^p=(\overline z)^q$

$z^q=(\overline z)^p$

Therefore

$z^{p-q}=(\overline z)^{q-p}.$

With $p\not=q$ taking absolute values of this last equation forces $z=0$ or $|z|=1$. The former gives one solution, the latter implies $\overline z=1/z$ and thence $z^p=1/z^q$. Thereby, nonzero solutions must be $(p+q)$-order roots of unity giving $p+q+1$ solutions in all.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: This assumes $p$ and $q$ are positive integers. Is that the case, @KshitijKumar ?

Comment: @MPW Ig Yeah, question didn't explicitly mentioned about it.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is using Euler's identity. If $p\neq q$ and $r\neq 0$ you get

$z=r\cdot e^{i\varphi}$. This results in
$$(r\cdot e^{i\varphi})^p=\overline{(r\cdot e^{i\varphi})^q}$$
$$r^pe^{ip\varphi}=r^qe^{-iq\varphi}$$
$$r^{p-q}e^{i\varphi(p+q)}=1$$
from which you deduce that
$$\varphi(p+q)=2n\pi\quad n\in\mathbb{Z}$$
$$\varphi=\frac{2n}{(p+q)}\pi\quad n\in\mathbb{Z}$$